# Trouble tracing cassandra query

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am experiencing really poor performance with Cassandra 2.1.5. I am new to this so would appreciate any advice on how to debug. Here is what my table looks like:

```
Keyspace: nt_live_october                                                                                                                                                                                    x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Read Count: 6                                                                                                                                                                                        x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Read Latency: 20837.149166666666 ms.                                                                                                                                                                 x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Write Count: 39799                                                                                                                                                                                   x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Write Latency: 0.45696595391844014 ms.                                                                                                                                                               x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Pending Flushes: 0                                                                                                                                                                                   x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Table: nt                                                                                                                                                                                    x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            SSTable count: 12                                                                                                                                                                            x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Space used (live): 15903191275                                                                                                                                                               x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Space used (total): 15971044770                                                                                                                                                              x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0                                                                                                                                                           x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Off heap memory used (total): 14468424                                                                                                                                                       x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.1308103413354315                                                                                                                                                x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Number of keys (estimate): 740                                                                                                                                                               x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Memtable cell count: 43483                                                                                                                                                                   x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Memtable data size: 9272510                                                                                                                                                                  x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0                                                                                                                                                             x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Memtable switch count: 17                                                                                                                                                                    x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Local read count: 6                                                                                                                                                                          x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Local read latency: 20837.150 ms                                                                                                                                                             x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Local write count: 39801                                                                                                                                                                     x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Local write latency: 0.457 ms                                                                                                                                                                x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Pending flushes: 0                                                                                                                                                                           x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Bloom filter false positives: 0                                                                                                                                                              x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000                                                                                                                                                            x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Bloom filter space used: 4832                                                                                                                                                                x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 4736                                                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Index summary off heap memory used: 576                                                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 14463112                                                                                                                                          x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 6867                                                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 30753941057                                                                                                                                               x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 44147544                                                                                                                                                     x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0                                                                                                                                        x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0                                                                                                                                        x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0                                                                                                                                        x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

I am issuing the following query via cqlsh:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> TRACING ON;                                                                                                                                                                                          Tracing is already enabled. Use TRACING OFF to disable.                                                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cassandra@cqlsh> CONSISTENCY;                                                                                                                                                                                x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Current consistency level is ONE.                                                                                                                                                                            x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cassandra@cqlsh> select * from nt_live_october.nt where group_id='254358' and epoch >=1444313898 and epoch<=1444348800 LIMIT 1;                                                                              x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=XXX.203
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds
```

and here is what system_traces.events shows:

> xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           1281 |             Parsing select * from nt_live_october.nt where group_id='254358'\nand epoch >=1443916800 and epoch<=1444348800\nLIMIT 30;
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           2604 |                                                                                                                   Preparing statement
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           8454 |                                                                                             Executing single-partition query on users
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           8474 |                                                                                                          Acquiring sstable references
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           8547 |                                                                                                           Merging memtable tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           8675 |                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 1
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           8685 |                                                                                           Seeking to partition beginning in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           9040 |                                                             Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           9056 |                                                                                            Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           9120 |                                                                                                     Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |           9854 |                                                                                                                  Read-repair DC_LOCAL
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10033 |                                                                                             Executing single-partition query on users
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10046 |                                                                                                          Acquiring sstable references
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10105 |                                                                                                           Merging memtable tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10189 |                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 1
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10198 |                                                                                           Seeking to partition beginning in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10248 |                                                             Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10261 |                                                                                            Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          10296 |                                                                                                     Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          12511 |                                                                                                Executing single-partition query on nt
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          12525 |                                                                                                          Acquiring sstable references
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          12587 |                                                                                                           Merging memtable tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          18067 |                                                                                             speculating read retry on /xxx.xxx.xxx.205
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          18577 |                                                                                 Sending READ message to xxx.xxx.xxx.205/xxx.xxx.xxx.205
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          25534 |                                                                              Partition index with 6093 entries found for sstable 8885
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          25571 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          34989 |                                                                              Partition index with 5327 entries found for sstable 8524
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          35022 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          36322 |                                                                               Partition index with 333 entries found for sstable 8477
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |          36336 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         714242 |                                                                            Partition index with 299251 entries found for sstable 8541
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         714279 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         715717 |                                                                               Partition index with 501 entries found for sstable 8217
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         715745 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         716232 |                                                                               Partition index with 252 entries found for sstable 8888
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |         716245 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |             87 |                                                                                            READ message received from /xxx.xxx.xxx.203
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |          50427 |                                                                                                Executing single-partition query on nt
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |          50535 |                                                                                                          Acquiring sstable references
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |          50628 |                                                                                                           Merging memtable tombstones
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |         170441 |                                                                             Partition index with 35650 entries found for sstable 6332
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |       30718026 |                                                                            Partition index with 199905 entries found for sstable 5958
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |       30718077 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |         170499 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |         248898 |                                                                             Partition index with 30958 entries found for sstable 6797
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.205 |         248962 |                                                                                     Seeking to partition indexed section in data file
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |       67814573 |                  Read timeout: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
>    xxx.xxx.xxx.203 |       67814675 |                                                                                                  Timed out; received 0 of 1 responses

I have 4 nodes, with replication factor of 3(one node is very light but it's not .203) The data I'm trying to read isn't very much -- even if LIMIT 1 is not being pushed to the remote node, the low end of the interval should be about 3 hours ago (I have no epochs past the current time)

Any tips on how to fix this/what might be going wrong? My cassandra version is 2.1.9, running largely with defaults

Table schema is as follows (I can't publish the whole schema for privacy reasons, but showing the keys which I hope is the main thing that matters)

```
PRIMARY KEY (group_id, epoch, group_name, auto_generated_uuid_field)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (epoch ASC, group_name ASC, auto_generated_uuid_field ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 7776000
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

___________EDIT_____________
to answer questions from below:

output of status:

```
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack                                                                                                                    x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DN  xxx.xxx.xxx.204  15.8 GB    1       ?       32ed196b-f6eb-4e93-b759  r1                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.205  20.38 GB   1       ?       446d71aa-e9cd-4ca9-a6ac  r1                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.202  1.48 GB    1       ?       2a6670b2-63f2-43be-b672  r1                                                                                                                      x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.203  15.72 GB   1       ?       dd26dfee-82da-454b-8db2  r1
```

The system.log is trickier as I have a lot of logging in there...one suspect thing I see is

```
 WARN [CompactionExecutor:6] 2015-10-08 19:44:16,595 SSTableWriter.java (line 240) Compacting large partition nt_live_october/nt:254358 (230692316 bytes)
```

but it's just a warning...shortly after I see

```
 INFO [CompactionExecutor:6] 2015-10-08 19:44:16,642 CompactionTask.java (line 274) Compacted 4 sstables to [/cassandra/data_dir_d/nt_live_october/nt-72813b106b9111e58f1ea1f0942ab78d/nt_live_october-nt-ka-9024,].  35,733,701 bytes to 30,186,394 (~84% of original) in 34,907ms = 0.824705MB/s.  21 total partitions merged to 18.  Partition merge counts were {1:17, 4:1, }
```

I see quite a few of these pairs in the log...but no ERROR level messages. Compaction seems to be going OK..it does say that this is the largest column family but all messages are INFO level....

Comment: Can you check the system.log usually in /var/log/cassandra/ and look for any warnings for large partitions, large amounts of tombstones, and nodes coming up and down? An output of nodetool status might help us as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the DN status of the node 204 means down. Retrieve its system.log and look for :

- Exceptions and ERROR level logs
- Anormal GC activity ( collection longer than 200ms)
- StatusLogger

Second, the data is badly distributed among the cluster. The load of 202 is only 1.48 GB. I suspect you have some very large partitions replicated on the other nodes. What is the replication factor ? What is the scheme of your keyspace ? You can answer these questions with cqlsh command :

```
DESCRIBE KEYSPACE nt_live_october;
```

Comment: Thanks Dine. Yes, 204 is down. But I do have a replication factor of 3, so the other 3 nodes should have plenty of data. I would not expect single node going down to degrade the performance so terribly. I will put the schema in the original question

Comment: No ERROR but I do see GC pauses of about 5K ms so I'll work on these. Thanks for the hint. I'll keep this open until I see if that solves all my issues

Comment: I am pretty sure you are querying a very big partition. Let me explain.

In the PRIMARY_KEY, the first given column is the partition key. Every insert with the same partition key is assigned to the same token and so written in the same replicas.

Here I see that 3 of your nodes hold a bigger volume of data than the last one. I suspect you always write in nt_live_october with the same partition_key. When querying this partition, if you do not specify the row keys, Cassandra is asked for manipulating a big in memory collection of data which will be long and will cause timeout.

Comment: You can solve this problem by increasing read_request_timeout_in_ms in your cassandra.yaml files. But I do not recommend it to you ! Timeouts prevent Cassandra from overload, which causes long GCs and OutOfMemories. Instead you should rethink your schema and queries. With Cassandra, a lot of small queries over several partitions is often better than a few big queries. Because it distributes work over the nodes and drain the memory continuously.